# No error but list is not displaying in customized listview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

After logging i need to display a list where it contains username and their description.

I am using customized listview where it is not showing any error but list is not showing.

I tried with all the solution from stackoverflow but it not showing the list.

The data is displaying in proper JSON format in server.

Fetch it from server.

```
 @Override
    protected descusers doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("descCrip", user.descCrip));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                + "fetchdesc.php");

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse;
            httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            //  JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            //JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("");

            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject e=json.getJSONObject(i);

                String username = e.getString("username");
                String descCrip = e.getString("descCrip");

                dusers.add(new descusers(username,descCrip));


            }
            descAdapter = new DescAdapter(descStore.this,dusers);
            mViews.lists.setAdapter(descAdapter);


          /* if (jObject.length() != 0){
                Log.v("happened", "2");
                String name = jObject.getString("name");
                int age = jObject.getInt("age");

                returnedUser = new User(name, age, user.username,
                        user.password);
            }*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Custom Adapter:

```
public class DescAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private final descStore ds;
private ArrayList<descusers> dusers;

public DescAdapter(descStore ds, ArrayList<descusers> dusers) {
    this.ds = ds;
    this.dusers = dusers;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dusers.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dusers.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    descusers du = dusers.get(position);
    String username = du.username;
    String descCrip=du.descCrip;

    View view= LayoutInflater.from(ds).inflate(R.layout.customlist,null);
    TextView uname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.username);
    TextView desc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.description);

    uname.setText(username);
    desc.setText(descCrip);

    return view;
}  
}
```

Customlist.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="username"
    android:textColor="#ff6aa9ff"
    android:textSize="20dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:text="Suggest a food to try"
    android:textColor="#ff06010b"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
```

listview.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.snatarajan.fooddoof.loginregister.descStore">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/post"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/post"
    android:hint="Suggest a food to try" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/post"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="post" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/post"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lists"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/post"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `AsyncTask`.
`doInBackground` (as the name suggests...) is executed in a background thread. Setting the adapter on your list needs to be done on the UI thread. So I think it will be enough for you to move the `mViews.lists.setAdapter(descAdapter);` call in the `onPostExecute` (which will execute on the UI thread).

On a different note, not related to your problem, I suggest you to read about the `ViewHolder` pattern when using `ListViews`, to improve performance,

**Addition**: This is what I changed from your original post:

I had to replace your http&json part with a dummy list creation:

```
ArrayList<YourAdapter.descusers> dusers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    dusers.add(new YourAdapter.descusers("username", "descCrip"));
descAdapter = new YourAdapter(<your_context>, dusers);
```

And in `onPostExecute`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong)
{
    super.onPostExecute(aLong);
    list.setAdapter(descAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Its not working even after adding mViews.lists.setAdapter(descAdapter); in   onPostExecute

Comment: I updated the answer with what worked for me. Do you see the data in your 'AsyncTask''s 'doInBackground'? Do you call execute on task? Is it throwing any exceptions and not make it to the adapter initialization line?